# Test if a file exists with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115141/check-if-a-file-exists-locally-using-javascript-only). But I have tried three of the answers with no good luck. I am using a system called Niagara which is acting as a web server, which may be the reason these techniques did not work. Nonetheless, I feel there must be a way to check for the existence of a file, not the existence of a 404 or 200 or 0.

Comment: What do want to check where for a file? Is the browser checking the user's local system? Is the webserver checking for a file on a remote host? Is the browser checking for the file on the server? Some other combination?

Comment: @AlexWayne The users browser would check for a file on the internet.

Comment: On your own webserver or someone elses? Is `mydomain.com/mypage.html` checking on a file somewhere like `somewhereelse.com/somefile.txt`? Or is `mydomain.com/mypage.html` check on a file somewhere like `mydomain.com/somefile.txt`?

Comment: @AlexWayne I would like the answer to work for both circumstances, if possible, but currently I will be looking on the same domain that is checking.

Comment: If it's on the same domain, @karthikr has the answer.  But on other domains it's not that simple due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Which means you cannot achieve this without their server letting you, or proxying the request through your own server, both of which are a bit more complicated.

Comment: Also it's worth noting that "existence of a file" is a bit vague. Yes, many web servers serve "files" directly from the file system. But ultimately most of the time it is an HTTP request and an HTTP response.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `$.ajax`

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'example.com/abc.html', //or your url
  success: function(data){
    alert('exists');
  },
  error: function(data){
    alert('does not exist');
  },
})
```

Comment: will this work with relative paths, lets say i just have url: 'abc.html'?

Comment: That answer was given on one of the referenced questions. Why is this different?

Comment: and what about a fail alert?

Comment: Refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript?answertab=oldest#tab-top This answer is essentially the same

Comment: @watson implement the `error` callback for the fail alert

Comment: @watson http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/