# Javascript check whether a file exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file, exists

I am attempting to work out whether an image exists in javascript using the code below:

```
var image_url = 'http://www.tester.co.uk/shop/images/product_thumbs/t_' + prod.images.toLowerCase() + '.jpg';

        $.ajax({
            url: image_url,
            type:'HEAD',
            error:
            function(msg_no){
                console.log("fail."); 
                markup += "<td class='movie-image'><img src='/shop/html_templates/files/images/default-category-image.gif'/></td>";
            },
            success:
            function(msg_yes){
                console.log("success."); 
                markup +=  "<td class='movie-image'><img src='/shop/images/product_thumbs/t_" + prod.images.toLowerCase() + ".jpg'/></td>";
            }
        });
```

On the 404 pages my console log shows the fail message, however on the pages returning 200 I am not getting the success message.

I'm hoping someone can advise me on where I'm going wrong!

Thanks

Comment: Surely if the file does not exist and the server returns `200`, it is the server that is doing it wrong

Comment: Hi, no the image isn't cross domain.

Comment: Hi, it's for a search facility so it returns multiple requests in one go, then it shows a 404 for the images that don't exist and can't be displayed - and in the console it displays the message I've put above - "fail" - but then if the image does exist it displays a 200 but doesn't enter my success function and display the console.log(success)

Comment: similar stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553174/test-if-a-file-exists-with-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at what you are actually doing, it might be wiser for you to not do this by `ajax` and instead rely on *Image*, which will throw an *error* if the returned data is not an (understood by browser) image, too.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onerror = function (msg_no) {
    console.log("fail."); 
    markup += "<td class='movie-image'><img src='/shop/html_templates/files/images/default-category-image.gif'/></td>";
}
img.onload = function (msg_yes) {
    console.log("success."); 
    markup +=  "<td class='movie-image'><img src='/shop/images/product_thumbs/t_" + prod.images.toLowerCase() + ".jpg'/></td>";
}
img.src = image_url; // fetch after listeners attached
```