# jQuery Validate file after filename change: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I currently have the following input:

```
<input id="attachments_0_file" name="attachments[0][file]" type="file">
```

When the user selects a file as so:

[image]

And he continues the process everything works fine as designed.

But when the user uploads a file as before and changes the filename in explorer/finder the whole thing "crashes" Chrome (testing browser) it returns:

**Error code: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**

Is there anyway to do a pre-check via jQuery?

**EDIT1**

```
  $("#apply_button").bind('click', function(e) {
            alert($( "#attachments_0_file" ).val());
        $.ajax({
          url: $( "#attachments_0_file" ).val(),
          success: function(data){
            alert('exists');
          },
          error: function(data){
            alert('does not exist');
          },
        })
      });
```

**EDIT2**

Create JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VWOU/t2MEz/5/

**EDIT 3**

Question Update: I want to check if the user maybe deleted the file or changed the file after he has selected the file for upload in the input box. So I can anticipate this and throw a warning.

**EDIT 4 When testing with a valid file I receive this**
[image]

Comment: You mean if the user change the file name on the file system?

Comment: @NkSP this is correct. It is possible to check this because it's implemented at www.imgur.com. But I don't know how.

Comment: DUPLICATE here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553174/test-if-a-file-exists-with-javascript]

Comment: @NkSP quick and dirty I tried EDIT1 with a working file and I retrieved does not exist. The path shows "C:/fakepath/zzz.png". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think that u see fakepath because you can not access to the complete path throw a browser  (secuity reason). But if you try to read the file you will get the excpetion, so handle that

Comment: @NkSP I shouldn't get an exception when trying with a valid file that because the file name isn't changed. If I read the post you of the duplicate correctly.

Comment: I do not get your problem. Try to open the file and if you get an exception handle that. I think that you can not check for the file. You won t be able to get the file path

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50887/discussion-between-vinozio-and-nk-sp)