# Error when user selects a file to upload and then changes the name

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `FileUpload` element on a page. Next to it is a label that shows the result of the upload attempt, and below it is a button that the user can select to perform the upload.

```
<p>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="InputUpload" runat="server" />
    <asp:label id="LabelResult" runat="server" />
</p>
<p>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonUpload" Text="Upload" 
        OnClick="ButtonUpload_Click" />
</p>
```

For the more visual minded folks, here's a picture:

[image]

The client (the user) performs the following actions in order:

1. Click on the Choose File button

   - This pops open a dialogue that allows the user to choose a file.
2. Select a file named Foo.txt
3. Change the name of the file to Bar.txt

   - This is done on the client's machine, not in my code.
4. Click Upload

At this point, the page crashes. I get the following message in Chrome:

> This webpage is not found
>
> ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I set break points in `Page_Load()` and `ButtonUpload_Click()` to try to figure out what is going on, but it doesn't look like control ever returns to my page. I think Chrome has an issue while trying to post with a file whose name changed some time after it was selected. Is it possible for me to capture this error server-side so that the page doesn't just crash?

If there is code that I didn't include that I need to, let me know. Like I mentioned, I set break points at the very first line of code in `ButtonUpload_Click()`, and it wasn't hit, so I assume that posting that code would not be helpful.

After further testing, it appears that this only happens in Chrome. I test in Firefox and Internet Explorer, and the file was uploaded using the name that it had when it was first selected.

Comment: Have you tried with another browser so you can make sure it is chrome's issue (Which I don't think so) And also, can you please provide the code how do you update the name of the file?

Comment: @curiousBoy The user changes the name of the file on their machine using Windows. There's no code for that - you just right click on the file and click on "Rename". I tested on Firefox and Internet Explorer and did not get the same issue. I'll edit the question to make it clear that this only happens in Chrome. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: maybe not the best solution but, once the file is uploaded , get the file name (string fName = FileUploadXX.Filename;) and then rename/set "fName" variable in the rest of the code! That should be fine I think

Comment: If I get it correct, user renames the file (let's say windows machine) by right clicking and renaming the file right? Have you tried to get file name again (basically refresh just like they just added a new file) when the Upload button is clicked?

Comment: Also this could be a chrome's caching issue as well

Comment: @curiousBoy The page crashes before my server side code is executed. So, I guess I have to check if the file exists on the client side before posting back. It turns out that my question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/23133096/3224483, but that question is also unanswered. After more digging, it turns out that checking for the existence of a file on the client is not allowed, although IE got around this in the past with ActiveX. I'm not sure how to solve this with Chrome.

Comment: Actually, I thought of one solution. I could take away the upload button and just upload the file the moment they select it, so that the user doesn't have time to change the name of the file.

Comment: Well if you have that flexibility, once they click select file,  you can also create an exact same file (whatever the file is- I assume it is not something too big) immediately and use that. Then let them however they renamed the original one.

Comment: @curiousBoy Sorry, I don't understand your comment. What do you mean by "create an exact same file", and how is that different from what I suggested (upload the file immediately)? Isn't creating a copy the same as uploading?

Comment: @Rainbolt,  did u solve this ?

Comment: @AnoopB.K No. It is still a known issue. The scenario that leads to it happening is somewhat contrived, so we decided not to spend time working around it.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correct, you are trying to overwrite FileUpload.FileName property.

> [FileUpload.FileName Property:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filename(v=vs.110).aspx) **Gets** the name of a file on a client to
>   upload using the FileUpload control.

Try using something like:

```
string fName = FileUpload1.FileName;
```

Then use `fName` for the rest of the steps (wherever you want to rename, overwrite `fName` variable). You can also pass fName to the server if you want it to be uploaded with that name!

If you want to do that on client side, you can use JQuery:

```
  var fName =  $('#FileUpload1').prop("files")['name'];
```

Then set fName however you want.

Comment: I am not overwriting the name of any file. The user is renaming the file on their local machine after they select it for upload, but before they push the "Upload" button. Again, **the user** is renaming the file, not my code.