# Detecting 404 code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I need to be able to detect a missing image in JavaScript.

PHP on the server can't be used because the href is computed by JavaScript. 
Script that works when the file exists is:

```
Data_ID = _DataRow.getDataItem()["Data_ID"];// Picks up the ID of the data
   _HitJPG = document.getElementById("HitJPG");
JPGFileName = _DataRow.getDataItem()["JPGFileName"];
directory = JPGFileName.slice(0, 10);
directory = directory.replace(/-/g, "/");

_HitJPG.innerHTML = "<a href=http://77.88.99.54/data/" + directory + "/" + JPGFileName + " ><h3>JPG File for this Data </h3>" + JPGFileName + "</a>";
```

How can I detect a HTTP 404 code before I set the "InnerHTML" in the Div?

Comment: You could always use jQuery, the `ajax` function in it helps a lot, and sorts cross browser issues.

Comment: Do an AJAX request and wait for a response. (You do **not** need jQuery for this simple task.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `onload` and `onerror` events to detect wether or not the image can be loaded

```
var Data_ID     = _DataRow.getDataItem()["Data_ID"];
var _HitJPG     = document.getElementById("HitJPG");
var JPGFileName = _SETIDataRow.getDataItem()["JPGFileName"];//"2014-04-29T13-36-27.JPG"
var directory   = JPGFileName.slice(0, 10);

directory = directory.replace(/-/g, "/");

var image = new Image();

image.onerror = function() {
    // fail - image not available
}

image.onload = function() {
    // success - image available

    _HitJPG.innerHTML = "<a href=http://77.88.99.54/data/" + directory + "/" + JPGFileName + " ><h3>JPG File for this Data </h3>" + JPGFileName + "</a>";
}

image.src = "http://77.88.99.54/data/" + directory + "/" + JPGFileName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using ajax call as said in above answer. Let me give u the code snippet:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '<image file name>', // your file name
  success: function(data){
    alert('exists');
  },
  error: function(data){
    alert('does not exist');
  },
})
```

The above code was already given in stackoverflow for other javascript related questions. You may check that also for clarification.

[Test if a file exists with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553174/test-if-a-file-exists-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "your iamge url" )
.done(function() {
alert( "success" );
})
.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
})
.always(function() {
alert( "complete" );
});
```

Reference http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with **ajax** request, when you get the response from the server, check the response **status**, example of **javascript/jQuery** function:

```
function fileExists(urlToCheck){
    var fileFound = true;
    $.ajax({
       url: urlToCheck,
       type: "GET",
       success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
           console.log(xhr.status);
           if(xhr.status == 404) fileFound= false;
       },
       complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
           console.log(xhr.status);
           if(xhr.status == 404) fileFound= false;
       } 
    });
    return fileFound;
}
```

I think this function can be improved much more, by considering the different HTTP response codes, codes different from 404 but which doesn't mean that the file exists in the server.